# String length Swift

Tags: string, swift, uitextfield, string-length

Something that has been driving me crazy is finding a simple thing: String length in Swift.

No, you cannot use `string.length`

No, you cannot use `string.characters.count`

No, you cannot use `string.count`

The only thing that works for me is `string.endIndex`. That however does not work for a simple textField check, e.g.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.endIndex > 20 {
        setBorder(descriptionField, finished: true)
    } else {
        setBorder(descriptionField, finished: false)
    }
}
```

Since endIndex is not an Int and cannot be converted into in. This whole thing is driving me crazy, I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use count()

```
count(textView.text)
```

in swift 2.0 some of the stuff you mentioned works =]

Answer (score 4):

Apple have changed how to handle this this a few times which will make a lot of existing documentation out of date.

If you're using Swift 2 and above, use -

`textView.text.characters.count`

If you're using Swift 1.2, it's -

`count(textView.text)`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0, it is 
string.characters.count